# Create event listener for Hindi numbers

Tags: java, swing, internationalization, jtextarea

When writing input in Swing `JTextArea` with keyboard layout switched to **Arabic** with **Hindi** numbers the input is written instead in **Arabic** numbers. While system wide apps writes numbers as **Hindi**. Is there a way to solve that?

Comment: you mean to say, its Arabic numbers only if you type in `jtextarea` and at rest places its Hindi numbers? Please specify your OS too.

Comment: I'm on Windows. When I type anywhere in any windows application it writes Hindi when I switch the keyboard layout while in java no matter what keyboard layout I am on it writes Arabic numerals.